# QT LICENSING issue

Tags: qt, license-key

I've downloaded qt 4.5.0 evaluation but during installation it asks for a license key but I don't have a one so please help me out.

Is there any way by which I can download a free GPL or LGPL license key for qt 4.5.0 or I would have to download the full qt SDK for windows????

I know it's a noobish question but I ll be really thankful to you guys.

Thnx in advance :-)

Comment: Why don't you use a more recent version of Qt?

Answer (score 1):

2 minutes of looking at the QT site would have answered this..

QT Framwork only downloads:
MinGW: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp
MSVS: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008